# Bridging header file Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I want to manually create a Obj-C bridging header file for my new Swift project for use with AudioKit. I am stuck. Everything seems to be correct (I even checked whether a space at the end of the file path was the problem and it isn't, and I cleared the project). As a proof I include a screenshot:

[image]

What could be wrong?

Comment: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift" did you check this? I hope here you will get the answer

Comment: No, none of these seem to work.

Comment: The naming convention is `<#YourProjectName#>-Bridging-Header.h`. The most reliable way is to let Xcode create the bridging header.

Comment: You need to also make sure that the path is correct in the target build settings.  Search for bridging header under build setting and make sure that the path lines up

Answer (score 0):

The name of the bridging header should be of the format

`<target_name>-Bridging-Header.h`

So if your target name is AudioMeter. Then the name of the bridging header should be

`AudioMeter-Bridging-Header.h`

Also make sure the path of the bridging header is specified in Xcode **Build Settings** under **Objective-C Bridging Header** option.

Comment: Be aware that bridging header paths are cAsE-sensitive in XCode, in case you added "MyProject-Bridging-header.h" instead of "MyProject-Bridging-Header.h". After changing it, you'll need to clear any .pch files (Precompiled Header C) from your project, which reside in `Build/Intermediates.noIndex/PrecompiledHeaders` somewhere.