# Can't use module I just install using cocoaPods (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm trying to use JSQMessagesViewController library but I can't seem to install it correctly... I can't import JSQMessagesViewController because Xcode tells me it doesn't exist.

I installed it using cocoa pods, the same way I installed Firebase and GoogleMaps... I can import and use those two, but it just doesn't work, somehow, with JSQMessages.

Any one has an idea why?

The error says "No such module 'JSQMessagesViewController'"

So I got it fixed.
If anyone want my pod file, it is the following:

```
     source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
     platform :ios, '8.0'
     use_frameworks!
     target 'MyProject'
     pod 'GoogleMaps'
     pod 'Firebase'
     pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In order to use CocoaPods written in Swift, you must explicitly include **use_frameworks!** to opt into using frameworks. If you forget to include this, and CocoaPods detects you’re trying to use a Swift CocoaPod,

for ex :

```
platform :ios, "9.0"
use_frameworks!

pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
```

for more information see this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift)

Comment: I don't know if this was the answer, but I uninstall every pod I had, install them the same way, and it worked

Answer (score -1):

You have tagged this with Swift, so you probably haven't imported the framework in the bridging header file. The framework is in Objective-C, so you have to import it through the bridging header file. Try that, and see if you can make it work.

```
#import "JSQMessagesViewController.h"
#import "JSQMessage.h"
#import "JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource.h"
#import "JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource.h"
#import "JSQMessagesBubbleImage.h"
#import "JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory.h"
#import "UIColor+JSQMessages.h"
#import "JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.h"
#import "JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h"
#import "JSQSystemSoundPlayer+JSQMessages.h"
#import "JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter.h"
#import "JSQPhotoMediaItem.h"
```

I didn't use cocoa pods when I used it in my project, but I still have to use the bridging header file.

Comment: Where is this bridging header file located? I am really new to iOS dev... and I feel this is a really noob question.

Comment: do a search here for bridging header file. This is one of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845104/bridging-header-file-swift

Comment: You do not need to add this to your bridging header that will actually throw more errors.